# Fabric JS Custom cursor style

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I need to change the cursor types as "Handwriting" on hover shapes...

```
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('ImgCanvas');
function changeCursor(cursorType) {
canvas.defaultCursor = "Handwriting";
}
```

I tried this but not working

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can change the hoverCursor directly to the single shape, or globally to the entire canvas. Take a look to the snippet below.

```js
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
// pointer for all
canvas.hoverCursor = 'pointer';

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 50,
  top: 30,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  fill: 'green',
  angle: 20,
});
var rect2 = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 180,
  top: 30,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  fill: 'green',
  angle: 20,
});
canvas.add(rect);
canvas.add(rect2);
canvas.renderAll();

var canvas2 = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c2');
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 120,
  top: 30,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  fill: 'green',
  angle: 20,
  // pointer for the selected shape
  hoverCursor: "pointer"
});
canvas2.add(rect);
canvas2.renderAll();
```

```css
p{font-family:'arial'}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/5.3.1/fabric.min.js"></script>

<p>Applied Globally</p>
<canvas height=200 width=300 id="c" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>

<p>Applied individually</p>
<hr/>
<canvas height=200 width=300 id="c2" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 8):

Surendhar,

To change cursor over the shape you need to defined as:

```
canvas.hoverCursor = 'cursor type'
```

This is a [list](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp) of cursors

If you need custom cursor you have to create **div** element on top the fabric canvas with custom cursor. When you have event 'mouseover' the shape just specified canvas.hoverCursor = 'none', and show custom one.

You can check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b93qdn5k/) it is simple example of custom cursor. You have to revisit this code in order to work without refreshing of custom cursor. It is all about mouse-over events of custom cursor. You have to disable mouse-over event of each **div** element of custom cursor.

Answer (score 3):

For fabric 4.6, besides the default cursors, also be able to set custom cursor with png:

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

const cursorUrl = 'https://ossrs.net/wiki/images/figma-cursor.png';
canvas.defaultCursor = `url(" ${cursorUrl} "), auto`;
canvas.hoverCursor = `url(" ${cursorUrl} "), auto`; 
canvas.moveCursor = `url(" ${cursorUrl} "), auto`;
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/winlinvip/pen/OJxOJgy?editors=0010)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple way to customize the cursor and create a hand grab effect when moving an object.

```
this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
      defaultCursor:'default',
      hoverCursor: 'grab',
      moveCursor:'grabbing',
      selection: true,
      backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    });
```

Here you find the list of all cursors

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_cursor&preval=alias

Answer (score 0):

To change the cursor of a fabric.js object, you can set the hoverCursor or moveCursor to your own image. 
E.g:

```
object.set({hoverCursor: 'url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/9632/happy.png"), auto'});
```